# Is it secure to store sensitive personal information in Evernote?

Tags: cloud-storage

I was trying to build my opinion about how safe it to upload to and store sensitive personal information at Evernote. Almost everything I've read points out that, as EN doesn't encrypt the information, it is not at all safe to store there much more than cooking recipes...

But suddenly I realized that the same happens with email providers, as Gmail.
Each time I send my address or my bank account by mail, that info is stored in Gmail servers as it would be in a note in Evernote servers, with more or less the same level of security... isn't it?

Then, if we don't mind storing mails in, for example, Gmail containing sensitive information, should we care about storing similar information in Evernote?

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance @DeerHunter (I'm new here, and it seems I can't do anything right!) but, what's a loaded question? I searched in help pages and didn't find an answer for that. I'm not an English native speaker so I did a search in the dictionary... do you mean "malicious"? if so... WHY????

Comment: Both options are equally insecure. You should trust neither Gmail nor Evernote. Your question is not malicious but gives the impression that Gmail is secure which it ain't.

Comment: But... if I literally said: "with more or less the same level of security... isn't it?" so I don't understand why I gave the impression that Gmail is secure (in fact I was asking that question). As I said I'm new here, but I'm in love with the way things work here and I'm trying to learn to speak "Stackexchangian language". That's why I appreciate every comment pointing out my flaws in it. And, thank you! Your statement: "both options are equally insecure" answers my question. I don't need any kind of high level security, I only wanted to know if EN has a reasonable level of security.

Comment: Naceira, I edited your question and removed my downvote. You'd do well to learn the difference between sensible and sensitive. Since Evernote doesn't encrypt your notes, it is not secure. As far as e-mail providers are concerned, you don't have to store sensitive information there - the very idea of e-mail is that you don't mind other people reading your communications. "Reasonable" level of security is a vague notion, so the question is likely to be closed as opinion-based unless you clarify what you deem "reasonably" secure.

Comment: Somehow related: [What type of encryption does Evernote use?](https://help.evernote.com/hc/en-us/articles/208314128-What-type-of-encryption-does-Evernote-use-)

Comment: I'm clueless about how to reword it in a valid way so it can be closed. I'll ask my doubts in Meta. Thank you very much for all the help!